# How to programatically get a list of 404 errors produced by Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

How can I get a list of 404 errors tomcat produced? Is there any JMX or other API to find resources (URIs) for which Tomcat respond 404?

## ANSWER

As mentioned in the accepted answer, I should have used [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html) feature in tomcat. Here is what I did:

1. Extended `org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve` and overrided [report() method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.14/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.java#ErrorReportValve.report%28org.apache.catalina.connector.Request,org.apache.catalina.connector.Response,java.lang.Throwable%29).
2. Added My valve to `server.xml` inside `<Host>` element:
   `<Valve className="my.package.HttpErrorValve" />`

Comment: The access log perhaps?

Comment: better to find it programatically

Comment: I'm sure I'll be corrected if I'm wrong, but I'm fairly sure that Tomcat does not keep any state of failed requests. If Tomcat kept the state of all failed requests in memory, a DOS attack would be trivial, it's usually very easy to find links that return 404 on a site so you could fill up memory very quickly.

Comment: You are right about the huge amount of memory it may require to keep track of all 404s, but how about list of **n** last 404 errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joachim said you can use the [access log valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) (%s,%r,...) to log 404 at runtime. If you override it you could make a combination of uri and date (maybe day) to prevent logging something twice or store it to a database for easier querying. To check for dead links in your code you can use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) tests.